# Is there a way to extract JavaScript variables from a page in Google Docs/with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm very new to JavaScript, and much more of an analyst than a programmer.

You know how you can open up Chrome's Console and type in a JavaScript variable, and the value of that variable will be returned? I want to know if it's possible to grab those variables from within Google Drive/Docs or Google Apps Script.

I've seen a few examples on StackOverflow of getting the values of certain XML elements (say, the text within a title tag), but I don't want to grab the entire contents of the script that contains these variables (as would be returned with an XPath query), just the variables themselves.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can exchage data between your web screen and you server side apps script by using the call

```
google.script.run.yourServerSideFunction(your parameters).
```

You can see more about server and client communications [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-communication?hl=en).

Comment: This is handy - I didn't know this functionality existed - but my plan was to get a list of URLs, put them in a Google Docs Spreadsheet, and then run the script against those URLs. This solution seems like it only works on a page-by-page basis, am I correct?

Comment: It works for thoese scripts that you have server side scripts and html with HtmlService client side pages. If you need to Fetch URL's from sppreadsheets use 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/

Comment: I don't think the script is server-side. The variables are set within the HTML of the page, like so:

`<script type="text/javascript">  
 metrics_level2  = "products";
 metrics_level3  = "products_and_services";
 metrics_level4  = "toys";
 metrics_pagename  = "site|products_and_services|toys"; 
</script> `

These are the variables I want to grab.

Comment: What kind of page? Can you provide an example?

Comment: You can make an URLFetch of the page and extract using regex the information that you need.